# Two WordPress sites on a particular host, loading way slower than other WP sites on other hosts

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I maintain 12 WordPress sites which run on several different hosts. Two of them are very slow loaders in particular, taking up to 30 seconds to load. The person who actually hosts those two for my client uses the same hosting company I use for my four sites. My sites load well, and they are more involved sites. I'm on a VPS setup. He is using a reseller setup for his care.

All the sites I maintain are using the Genesis Framework, and run very well on all the hosts, but these two have sporadic loading times and I cannot seem to get a clear answer from him why those two sites are having trouble being quick. I've installed database optimizers to run at 6 a.m. each day. These are not complicated sites, with just pictures and text. No extensive javascript use. Just pictures and text.

Here is my question... is there something about the initial connection to the site that would be an issue. To use an analogy, it's like trying to go into a house, but the door knobs are greased  and you can't get a good grip to do it, but all my other sites have clean dry knobs. Is there something that could happen when there is a site trying to make a connection by DNS that could cause a delay?

What makes this also more confusing is that when I try to do GTMetrix scores, it seems like it's taking a while for the site to get fetched, yet the site scores are coming up at 86% (B), which is pretty good. How am I getting an 86%/B rating when the site is taking so long to connect?

Any thoughts or insights would be appreciated. I feel like I'm getting no satisfactory answers from the host guy, and the client is getting antsy.

Comment: Is it forced to preload large images or videos, that must download before the page renders?  What's the total size of the site, as rendered in the browser (F12 to bring up developer console in Chrome and go to the Network tab, bottom left hand corner shows total page size).

Answer (score 0):

Some ways that I used to speed up my sites:

1. Disabling or limiting the frequency of WP Heartbeat.
2. Use CloudFlare CDN.
3. Turn the whole into static HTML (If not e-commerce sites). Good plugin to use WP2Static